# The getopts command not taking in multiple options that require an argument

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

I'm having problems with getopts command.

When I want to use an option that requires the SAME argument, it stops running the program after the first option that requires an argument (-i for example). 
 So when I want it to take the options  -id or -i -d it will stop running the while loop after the "-i" option is used and ignore the -d option.

How can I get the  loop to continue and for the -d option  to execute as well?

The format for the arguments passed can be: "-id argument" or "-i -d argument"

I'm using $p currently to grab the final argument to pass for each option currently.
this is linux ubuntu shell  in dash:

```
To make the code smaller and quicker to read:

for p do :; done

    echo arguments === $1 $2 $3 
    echo p = $p 
    while getopts ":hva:b:d:g:i:u:w:" opt; 
    do
        case "$opt" in

        i)
        checkdir $p
        fileinfo $p 
 ;;

        ***OTHER OPTIONS FOLLOW SIMILAR FORMAT***

        esac

    done
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: oh shoot sorry ill get on that in just a second

Comment: @oguzismail is this more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to use an option that requires an argument, it stops running the program after the first option that requires an argument (-i for example). So when I want it to take the options -id or -i -d it will stop running the while loop after the "-i" option is used.

If you *want it to take the options … -i -d*, you have to (since each of them *requires an argument*) supply an argument right after each option, e. g. `… -i argument1 -d argument2 …`.
With `-id` or `-i -d` the `d` or `-d`, respectively, is taken for the option's argument.

Comment: So I edited the question a bit to clarify, but the argument for both options will always be the same.  the getopts will work for the first argument and will then exit the while loop

Comment: Even if the second option _requires the SAME argument_, you are, as I wrote, required to **supply the argument right after each option**, e. g. `-i SAME -d SAME`. Reread the last sentence of my answer.